# Boost error, trouble compiling xtime.hpp

Tags: boost, compilation, makefile

I've been working on a C++ project using Boost, and between compiles, I must have upgraded something in boost without meaning to or something, because now Boost dependencies won't compile:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:14:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from /blah.h:4,
                 from bluh.h:3,
                 from bleh/main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:23:5: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:23:5: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:23:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:46:14: error: expected type-specifier before 'system_time'
In file included from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:14:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/mutex.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from /blah,
                 from /bleh,(changed these names, obviously)
                 from /bluh /main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp: In function 'int xtime_get(xtime*, int)':
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:73:40: error: 'get_system_time' was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:73:40: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:19:24: note:   'boost::get_system_time'
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp:88:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/edge_based_tracker.dir/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/edge_based_tracker.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas?  I tried changing TIME_UTC to TIME_UTC_ as this was recommended to me on another site, but that didn't seem to help.

EDIT: The Boost Version is Version: 1.48.0.2.  I've attached xtime below:

```
// Copyright (C) 2001-2003
// William E. Kempf
// Copyright (C) 2007-8 Anthony Williams
//
//  Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying 
//  file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

#ifndef BOOST_XTIME_WEK070601_HPP
#define BOOST_XTIME_WEK070601_HPP

#include <boost/thread/detail/config.hpp>

#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/conversion.hpp>

#include <boost/config/abi_prefix.hpp>

namespace boost {

enum xtime_clock_types
{
    TIME_UTC=1 //LINE 23
//    TIME_TAI,
//    TIME_MONOTONIC,
//    TIME_PROCESS,
//    TIME_THREAD,
//    TIME_LOCAL,
//    TIME_SYNC,
//    TIME_RESOLUTION
};

struct xtime
{
#if defined(BOOST_NO_INT64_T)
    typedef int_fast32_t xtime_sec_t; //INT_FAST32_MIN <= sec <= INT_FAST32_MAX
#else
    typedef int_fast64_t xtime_sec_t; //INT_FAST64_MIN <= sec <= INT_FAST64_MAX
#endif

    typedef int_fast32_t xtime_nsec_t; //0 <= xtime.nsec < NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND

    xtime_sec_t sec;
    xtime_nsec_t nsec;

    operator system_time() const
    {
        return boost::posix_time::from_time_t(0)+
            boost::posix_time::seconds(static_cast<long>(sec))+
#ifdef BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_NANOSECONDS
            boost::posix_time::nanoseconds(nsec);
#else
        boost::posix_time::microseconds((nsec+500)/1000);
#endif
    }

};

inline xtime get_xtime(boost::system_time const& abs_time)
{
    xtime res;
    boost::posix_time::time_duration const time_since_epoch=abs_time-boost::posix_time::from_time_t(0);

    res.sec=static_cast<xtime::xtime_sec_t>(time_since_epoch.total_seconds());
    res.nsec=static_cast<xtime::xtime_nsec_t>(time_since_epoch.fractional_seconds()*(1000000000/time_since_epoch.ticks_per_second()));
    return res;
}

inline int xtime_get(struct xtime* xtp, int clock_type)
{
    if (clock_type == TIME_UTC)
    {
        *xtp=get_xtime(get_system_time());
        return clock_type;
    }
    return 0;
}


inline int xtime_cmp(const xtime& xt1, const xtime& xt2)
{
    if (xt1.sec == xt2.sec)
        return (int)(xt1.nsec - xt2.nsec);
    else 
        return (xt1.sec > xt2.sec) ? 1 : -1;
}

} // namespace boost

#include <boost/config/abi_suffix.hpp>

#endif //BOOST_XTIME_WEK070601_HPP
```

EDIT: To make it clear, the code is failing on an import of boost/thread.hpp

Comment: It would be helpful if you said which version of Boost, and showed the code that is failing, and showed what's on line 23 of xtime.hpp, and reduced your code to a minimal example. In fact this question is impossible to answer as it stands.

Comment: I've editted the question to include the version of Boost, and xtime.hpp.  The code that's failing is just an import statement.

Comment: You don't have to copy&paste Boost code. Show *your* code that you attempt to compile.

Comment: Line 23 was asked for, and so I posed the Boost code so that Jonathan Wakely could see.  As I said in my previous comment, the code that's failing is an import statement, specifically boost/thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not show your code, we can only guess. My guess is that you define `TIME_UTC` macro somewhere in your code. This macro messes-up `xtime.hpp` header.

Comment: @user650261 Preprocess the whole translation unit and find this line in the preprocessed code.

Comment: Replace TIME_UTC with TIME_UTC_ as @noodlebox suggested

Answer (score 13):

For those running into the same issue and struggling to find the solution here.
Derived from noodlebox' link (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6940):

You can edit /usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp (or whereever your xtime.hpp lies)
and change all occurrences of **TIME_UTC** to **TIME_UTC_** - Probably around lines 23 and 71.

i.e. `sed -i 's/TIME_UTC/TIME_UTC_/g' /usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp`

Comment: sed -i 's/TIME_UTC/TIME_UTC_/g' /usr/include/boost/thread/xtime.hpp

Comment: Had this error compiling PCL 1.7.1 libraries whith boost 1.49.0. This solved this issue (but drove me to other error - oh my!).

Comment: I believe you also need to change libs/thread/src/pthread/timeconv.inl as it also contains the boost::TIME_UTC

Answer (score 7):

If you're getting syntax errors when using Boost, you may need to compile your code with `-std=c++11`.

The `TIME_UTC` issue you might have read about is a side effect of using c++11.  `TIME_UTC` is now defined as a macro in c++11, so you will need to either replace all instances of `TIME_UTC` with `TIME_UTC_`, or just use a newer (1.50.0+) version of Boost where this has been fixed already.

See: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6940

Comment: Small note: it's C11 (done by lib C's time.h), not C++11 (it's not restricted to C++)